# NSManaged Object initWithCoder Error

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a nasty bug and I would appreciate any guidance pointing me in the general direction of a solution. Occasionally, I get the following exception which pertains to calling initWithCoder on 3 different NSManagedObject subclasses in my core data model. If I delete the app from my device and reload it, or reset content on the simulator the exception goes away. No where in my code do I explicitly call initWithCoder on an NSManagedObject Subclass.

The bug seems to arise randomly after editing random parts of my source code. Any ideas on where to begin?

```
2014-01-11 15:59:22.078 Flip Evaluator and Manager[354:a0b] -[SellingCosts initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc2cec80
2014-01-11 15:59:22.079 Flip Evaluator and Manager[354:a0b] CoreData: error: exception during fetchRowForObjectID: -[SellingCosts initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc2cec80 with userInfo of (null)
2014-01-11 15:59:22.081 Flip Evaluator and Manager[354:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SellingCosts initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc2cec80'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01e9a5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c1d8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01f37903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01e8a90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01e8a4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Foundation                          0x01830b2a _decodeObjectBinary + 3498
    6   Foundation                          0x0182fc15 _decodeObject + 340
    7   Foundation                          0x0182fab9 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:] + 181
    8   Foundation                          0x018a168d +[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:] + 106
    9   Foundation                          0x018202e5 -[_NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformer transformedValue:] + 47
    10  CoreData                            0x0064bd09 _prepareResultsFromResultSet + 4105
    11  CoreData                            0x00649583 newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 1795
    12  CoreData                            0x0063448e -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 526
    13  CoreData                            0x0065302e -[NSSQLCore fetchRowForObjectID:] + 1198
    14  CoreData                            0x00650798 -[NSSQLCore newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 296
    15  CoreData                            0x00650667 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 71
    16  CoreData                            0x0064fa3b _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 411
    17  CoreData                            0x0064f897 -[NSFaultHandler fulfillFault:withContext:forIndex:] + 39
    18  CoreData                            0x0064f473 _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 259
    19  CoreData                            0x0064f2c6 _sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 70
    20  CoreData                            0x00653cd5 -[NSManagedObject(_PFDynamicAccessorsAndPropertySupport) _genericValueForKey:withIndex:flags:] + 85
    21  CoreData                            0x0068d781 _PF_Handler_Public_GetProperty + 161
    22  CoreData                            0x0068d685 -[NSManagedObject valueForKey:] + 149
    23  Flip Evaluator and Manager          0x00030c4c -[OzCalculator sumTheValuesInSet:withAttributeKeyForValue:] + 428
    24  Flip Evaluator and Manager          0x0002f7d5 -[OzCalculator sumMoreCostsAndUpdateDataModelFor:] + 165
    25  Flip Evaluator and Manager          0x0002edc1 -[OzCalculator performAllCalculationsOnProperty:] + 817
    26  Flip Evaluator and Manager          0x00002d37 -[OzPropertyConverter createAManagedPropertyFromAnEvaluatedProperty:] + 1175
    27  Flip Evaluator and Manager          0x00041233 -[OzHaveYouPurchasedThisProperty goForwardToNextView] + 307
    28  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c2f874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    29  UIKit                               0x0098d0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    30  UIKit                               0x0098d04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    31  UIKit                               0x00a850c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    32  UIKit                               0x00a85484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    33  UIKit                               0x00a841fd -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 254
    34  UIKit                               0x009ca34b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 386
    35  UIKit                               0x009cb184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    36  UIKit                               0x0099ee86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    37  UIKit                               0x0098918f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x01e2383f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x01e231cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x01e4029e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x01e3fac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x01e3f8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x02c2a9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    44  GraphicsServices                    0x02c2a809 GSEventRun + 104
    45  UIKit                               0x0098bd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    46  Flip Evaluator and Manager          0x0002e5dd main + 141
    47  libdyld.dylib                       0x030c1725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Code:

```
//
//  SellingCosts.h
//  Flip Evaluator and Manager
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Cost, Property, TotalCosts;

@interface SellingCosts : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * deedPrep;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * realtyCommisionAmount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * realtyCommisionPercent;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * totalCost;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *moreCosts;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Property *property;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TotalCosts *totalCosts;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * transferTaxAmount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * transferTaxPercent;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *totalIncompleteCost;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *totalCompleteCost;

@end
```

Here is the method that is called before things go wrong:

```
-(NSInteger)sumTheValuesInSet:(NSMutableSet *)set withAttributeKeyForValue:(NSString *)attributeKey
{
    NSInteger sumToReturn = 0;
    for (id obj in set) {
        sumToReturn = sumToReturn +[[obj valueForKey:attributeKey] integerValue];
    }

    return sumToReturn;
}
```

The method enumerates through `Cost` objects in the `NSSet` `[sellingCosts valueForKey:@"moreCosts"]`.

Here is the model for the `Cost` object//

```
//  Cost.h
//  Flip Evaluator and Manager
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class BuyingCosts, HoldingCosts, SellingCosts, OtherCosts, TotalCosts;

@interface Cost : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong)    BuyingCosts *buyingCosts;
@property (nonatomic, strong)    HoldingCosts *holdingCosts;
@property (nonatomic, strong)    SellingCosts *sellingCosts;
@property (nonatomic, strong)    OtherCosts *otherCosts;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TotalCosts *incompleteCosts;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TotalCosts *completedCosts;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *complete;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id costType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *amount;

@end
```

Comment: post details of the model and the subclass definitions. Do you have binary or transformable attributes?

Comment: There are no binary attributes. The class is pretty strait forward. No added methods to the subclass (implementation is posted).

Comment: What about transformable attributes (as Duncan asked above)?

Comment: No transformables. I know this doesn't give you much to go off of but it's all I have.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, without transformables or binary properties in my model.  I don't think this has to do with transformables.

Answer (score 0):

Share your model as well as this appears to be a transform problem at first glance.

You should also share the code in `-sumTheValuesInSet:withAttributeKeyForValue:` as that seems to be the last point in your code before things go wrong.

Comment: I added the code for the method you referred to. I would like to point out that the method references a Cost object which has a transformable property id costType which is a weak reference to a sellingCosts Object. Implementation for the Cost object is also shown.

Comment: So I managed to circumvent the issue using a hack solution. I added `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;` methods which return `self` to the particular NSManagedObject subclasses for which this is a problem. Is that a bad idea for  along term fix?

Comment: Yes that is a bandaid. You are not solving the problem.

Comment: That Transformable property CostType is surely the problem then? Why not use a relationship to the SellingCost object?